Uploaded package in github package are using number but jar is using all
I have an API that is built with gradle.  This issue appeared when I moved to Java 21 (from 17) and gradle 8.6 (from 8.3):  gradle is searching for myapi-dateOfDay-1.jar.
In the Github packages files are well registered. There is a jar known as myapi-dateOfDay-all.jar. There is pom file in maven-metadata.xml that refers to myapi-dateOfDay-1.pom.
As all of my projects that depend on this API find the pom.xml file and  do not complain about dependency resolution failure.  (But they don't get any jar file.)
How can I get gradle to find the jar file from the Github package?
Here is part of gradle file :
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id "maven-publish"
    id 'io.github.goooler.shadow' version '8.1.7'
}

java.toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "github"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyOrg/MyAPI")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials);
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        gpr(MavenPublication) {
            publication -> project.shadow.component(publication)
            groupId 'com.elikill58'
            artifactId 'myapi'
        }
    }
}

Here is the github actions that publish it:
name: Build with gradle

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        distribution: 'temurin'
        java-version: '21'
        cache: gradle
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build
      run: ./gradlew publish -PgithubAuthHeaderName='Authorization' -PgithubAuthHeaderValue='Bearer ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}'


I had to specify some specific jar name and be sure it's this one. Even the classifier wasn't took in count.
Here is my final gradle file:
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id "maven-publish"
    id 'io.github.goooler.shadow' version '8.1.7'
    id "eclipse"
}

java.toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "github"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyOrg/MyAPI")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials);
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
    publications {
        gpr(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("build/libs/MyAPI-version.jar") {
               builtBy shadowJar
            }
            groupId 'com.elikill58'
            artifactId 'myapi'
        }
    }
}

archivesBaseName = 'MyAPI'

sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
    resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('MyAPI')
    archiveClassifier.set(null)
}

build.dependsOn shadowJar

